# Why does the Solana JSON RPC server appear to be single threaded?

Tags: rpc, validator

Recently, I was looking at Solana's RPC code and I was surprised to see that the JSON RPC server seems to be single threaded? https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/0d92254736936fc9ffa68ebe4867233625a1b415/rpc/src/rpc_service.rs#L529

Is this correct? And if so, why is this the case? I know RPCs are typically run on fairly powerful machines, but I still think that multiple threads would result in a faster RPC.

Perhaps there are other more important bottlenecks I am not considering like reading accounts from the Validator? Or maybe this was done so that RPC requests don't degrade Validator performance too much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit confusing because it does look like 1 thread, but right before it's setting `event_loop_executor` and passing in a multi-threaded tokio runtime. This means that it's one thread running a multi-threaded executor.

The `threads()` function in the jsonrpc_http_service crate gives more info at https://docs.rs/jsonrpc-http-server/latest/jsonrpc_http_server/struct.ServerBuilder.html#method.threads:

> Sets number of threads of the server to run.

> Panics when set to 0. The first thread will use provided Executor instance and all other threads will use UninitializedExecutor to spawn a new runtime for futures. So it’s also possible to run a multi-threaded server by passing the default tokio::runtime executor to this builder and setting threads to 1.